# R Plotly: How to set the color of Individual Bars of a Waterfall Chart in R Plot.ly?

Tags: r, charts, plotly, waterfall

I am trying to change the color of the individual bars of a waterfall chart using R Plotly. More specifically the first and the last bar, I want it to be blue and yellow respectively. So in the below graph, Group 1 has to be blue and Group 2 has to be yellow.

[image: Waterfall Chart]

R Plotly Waterfall chart seems to only have the option to set three colors for increasing, decreasing and total bars.

Here is the code used to generate the above graph:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(Rank = 1:7, Variable = c("Group 1","A","B","C","D","E","Group 2"),
Value = c(10,2,2,2,1,1,20),
measure = c("relative","relative","relative","relative","relative","relative","total"),
colour = c("yellow","green","green","green","green","green","blue"))


df$Variable <- factor(df$Variable, levels = unique(df$Variable))
df$text <- as.character(round(df$Value,2))
df$Factor <- as.numeric(df$Variable)



plot_ly(df, name = "20", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
             x = ~Variable, textposition = "outside", y= ~Value, text =~paste0('$',text),
             hoverinfo='none',cliponaxis = FALSE,
             connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)"))
        ) %>%
  layout(title = "",
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = "",tickprefix ='$'),
         autosize = TRUE,
         showlegend = FALSE
         )
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> R Plotly Waterfall chart seems to only have the option to set three
>   colors for increasing, decreasing and total bars.

Unfortunaley, you seem to be absolutely right. But the good news is that plotly lets you add shapes to charts almost just as you'd like. And you're already able to set one of your preferred colors to Group2 via the `totals` color. So you only really need to add one shape to get:

[image]

I don't know if this will be possible to your real world data, but in works fine in this case. Here's how you do it:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(Rank = 1:7, Variable = c("Group 1","A","B","C","D","E","Group 2"),
Value = c(10,2,2,2,1,1,20),
measure = c("relative","relative","relative","relative","relative","relative","total"),
colour = c("yellow","green","green","green","green","green","yellow"))


df$Variable <- factor(df$Variable, levels = unique(df$Variable))
df$text <- as.character(round(df$Value,2))
df$Factor <- as.numeric(df$Variable)



p<-plot_ly(df, name = "20", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
             x = ~Variable, textposition = "outside", y= ~Value, text =~paste0('$',text),
             hoverinfo='none',cliponaxis = FALSE,
             connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)")),
             totals = list(marker = list(color = "yellow", line = list(color = 'yellow', width = 3)))
        ) %>%
  layout(title = "",
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = "",tickprefix ='$'),
         autosize = TRUE,
         showlegend = FALSE,


         shapes = list(
               list(type = "rect",
                    fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 1,
                    x0 = -0.4, x1 = 0.4, xref = "x",
                    y0 = 0.0, y1 = 10, yref = "y"))

         )
p
```

Would you like more shapes? Just add another in the `shapes` list in `layout` like this:

```
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(Rank = 1:7, Variable = c("Group 1","A","B","C","D","E","Group 2"),
Value = c(10,2,2,2,1,1,20),
measure = c("relative","relative","relative","relative","relative","relative","total"),
colour = c("yellow","green","green","green","green","green","yellow"))


df$Variable <- factor(df$Variable, levels = unique(df$Variable))
df$text <- as.character(round(df$Value,2))
df$Factor <- as.numeric(df$Variable)



p<-plot_ly(df, name = "20", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
             x = ~Variable, textposition = "outside", y= ~Value, text =~paste0('$',text),
             hoverinfo='none',cliponaxis = FALSE,
             connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)")),
             totals = list(marker = list(color = "yellow", line = list(color = 'yellow', width = 3)))
        ) %>%
  layout(title = "",
         xaxis = list(title = ""),
         yaxis = list(title = "",tickprefix ='$'),
         autosize = TRUE,
         showlegend = FALSE,


         shapes = list(
               list(type = "rect",
                    fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 1,
                    x0 = -0.4, x1 = 0.4, xref = "x",
                    y0 = 0.0, y1 = 10, yref = "y"),

               list(type = "rect",
                 fillcolor = "blue", line = list(color = "blue"), opacity = 0.2,
                 x0 = 3, x1 = 4, xref = "x",
                 y0 = 4, y1 = 12.5, yref = "y"))




         )
p
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm using Python. I searched but couldn't find the `shapes` option in the API. Would you mind taking a look kind sir?

Comment: @RodrikTheReader Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @vestland Unfortunately, no.

Comment: @RodrikTheReader If you post it as a question I will take a look.

Comment: It's been so long I barely remember what the context was. But I'll try and post this as a question when I get some spare time @vestland

Comment: @RodrikTheReader Ah, I see. Notging to worry too much about then.

Answer (score 0):

I have been tinkering around with the {waterfalls} package lately, which makes it easy to create and customize waterfall plots by leveraging {ggplot2} and most of its logic under the hood. The plots can easily be converted to {plotly} via the `ggplotly()` function afterwards.

If requested, the main function `waterfalls::waterfall()` calculates an overall sum on the fly, so there is no need to do the math manually. I am only keeping the last row from your sample data for my second, more advanced example on manual label placement.

```r
library(plotly)

## sample data
df = data.frame(
  Variable = c("Group 1", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "Group 2")
  , Value = c(10, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0)
  , Color = c("blue", rep("green", 5L), "yellow")
)

## convert column 'Variable' to `factor`
df$Variable = factor(
  df$Variable
  , levels = unique(df$Variable)
)
```

The following code snippet creates a basic waterfall plot. As mentioned earlier, there is no need for manual calculations as long as `calc_total = TRUE`, so the last row of data is discarded before generating the plot.

```
## discard row with overall sum
sbs = utils::head(
  df
  , n = -1L
)

## generate waterfall plot
p0 = waterfalls::waterfall(
  sbs
  , rect_text_labels = paste0("$", sbs$Value)
  , calc_total = TRUE
  , total_axis_text = "Group 2"
  , total_rect_text = paste0("$", sum(sbs$Value))
  , total_rect_color = "yellow"
  , total_rect_text_color = "black"
  , total_rect_border_color = "transparent"
  , fill_colours = sbs$Color
  , fill_by_sign = FALSE
  , rect_border = "transparent"
  , draw_axis.x = "front"
) + 
  labs(
    x = NULL
    , y = NULL
  ) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::dollar_format()
    , expand = c(0, 0)
  ) + 
  theme_minimal()

ggplotly(p0)
```

[image: base]

Let us also explore a second, more advanced example where the aim is to place labels at the top of each bar as shown in your example. Although there is an argument 'put_rect_text_outside_when_value_below
' that would allow to place labels outside the boxes, it does not seem to integrate with 'calc_total' – at least not with {waterfalls} package version `‘1.0.0’`. Instead, I am usiing `ggplot2::geom_text()` for a finer control over customized text annotations.

```r
## create custom labels
df$Text = ifelse(
  df$Variable == "Group 2"
  , cumsum(df$Value)
  , df$Value
)

## add offset for label placement (+5% of total)
df$Position = cumsum(df$Value) + 
  0.05 * sum(df$Value)

## generate advanced waterfall plot
p1 = waterfalls::waterfall(
  sbs
  # "turn off" text labels
  , rect_text_labels = rep("", nrow(sbs))
  , calc_total = TRUE
  , total_axis_text = "Group 2"
  # "turn off" total text label
  , total_rect_text = ""
  , total_rect_color = "yellow"
  , total_rect_border_color = "transparent"
  , fill_colours = sbs$Color
  , fill_by_sign = FALSE
  , rect_border = "transparent"
  , draw_axis.x = "front"
) + 
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = Variable
      , y = Position
      , label = paste0("$", Text)
    )
    , data = df
    , inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) + 
  labs(
    x = NULL
    , y = NULL
  ) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    labels = scales::dollar_format()
  ) + 
  theme_minimal()

ggplotly(p1)
```

[image: advanced]